# Open a specific directory in default file manager?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried many ways to open a specific directory in default File Manager in flutter.

```
 final directory = fileDirectory.substring(0, fileDirectory.lastIndexOf('/'));
          try {
            await OpenFile.open(directory );
          } on PlatformException catch (e) {
            print("Error opening directory: $e");
          }
```

it's not working. (i tried this on android 13)